# Extract part of an input string by scanf()

Tags: c, string, scanf

I ask my question by these two examples, in the first program when I enter my name it works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char str [20];

    while(1)
    {
       printf ("Enter your name: ");
       scanf ("%19s",str);
       printf ("Your name is %s\n",str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter your name: Reza
Your name is Reza
Enter your name:
```

But in the following program the result is not as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char str [20];

    while(1)
    {
        printf ("Enter your name: ");
        scanf ("name=%19s",str);
        printf ("Your name is %s\n",str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When entering **name=Reza** as the input, the program repeatedly print the output:

```
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
Enter your name: Your name is Reza
...
```

In your opinion what's the mistake?
Thank in advance

Comment: You're ignoring errors. Ask yourself what happens if `scanf` fails.

Comment: I agree with you, as David mentioned I should check the return of every input  function and handle errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained by a simple reference to `man scanf`. In your first case:

```
scanf ("%19s",str);
```

The `%s` conversion specifier ignores leading whitespace so the `'\n'` left in the input buffer (`stdin`) is silently consumed.

In your second case:

```
scanf ("name=%19s",str);
```

You *format string* is looking for a literal `"name="` as part of the input, which since the `'\n'` left after your prior input isn't consumed, a *matching failure* occurs because your input is actually `"\nname=..."`, character extraction ceases at that point leaving a characters in the input buffer unread -- leading to the same failure on every subsequent input.

You can solve the problem including an empty space at the beginning of your *format string* causing any leading whitespace to be consumed with:

```
scanf (" name=%19s",str);
```

Now you can input, for example:

```
name=Gary
name=Tom
...
```

(of course you will still have an extraneous character problem if the user enters more than 19-characters for any name -- or if a cat accidentally steps on the keyboard)

You must also ***check the return*** of EVERY input function used -- especially `scanf`. Simply check that the number of expected conversions takes place, e.g.

```
if (scanf (" name=%19s",str) != 1) {
    fputs ("error: conversion failed.\n", stderr);
    /* handle error */
}
```

Comment: Sure -- the other best advise is to read each line with `fgets()` (don't skimp on buffer size) and then pass the buffer to `sscanf` to parse what you need from it. That way you are guaranteed to consume an entire line each time `:)`

Comment: It's a better and cleaner solution.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the file stream in `fputs`... fixing that nit.

Comment: That's OK and I got the idea!